# Can I use `write!` and `file.write_all` in same fn?

Tags: rust

```
use std::fmt::Write;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut p = String::new();
    (1..6).for_each(|n| {
        write!(&mut p, "{},", n);
    });
    let mut file = File::create("a.csv")?;
    file.write_all(p.as_bytes())?;
    Ok(())
}
```

When compiled I got an error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `write_all` found for type `std::fs::File` in the current scope
```

and a warning:

```
warning: unused import: `std::io::Write`
```

How to concat an array to a string and write into a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since [Rust 1.33](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1330-2019-02-28) it is possible to use the [`underscore_imports` feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/56303/), which means you can write this:

```rust
use std::fmt::Write as _;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write as _;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut p = String::new();
    (1..6).for_each(|n| {
        write!(&mut p, "{},", n);
    });
    let mut file = File::create("a.csv")?;
    file.write_all(p.as_bytes())?;
    Ok(())
}
```

which brings all traits into scope without a clash in the namespace.

But, if you want to do something like

```rust
fn main() {
    Write::write_all(&mut file, p.as_bytes())
}
```

you have to import the correct trait again without the underscore.

Answer (score 6):

After fixing some typos in your code, we're left with this error on playgrounds compiler.

```
error[E0252]: the name `Write` is defined multiple times
  --> src/lib.rs:95:5
   |
94 | use std::fmt::Write;
   |     --------------- previous import of the trait `Write` here
95 | use std::io::Write;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Write` reimported here
   |
   = note: `Write` must be defined only once in the type namespace of this module
help: you can use `as` to change the binding name of the import
```

Your problem is that `Write` is imported twice. But since you're only pulling `std::io::Write` in to get to the trait - you can import it under any name you like. So just following the suggestion in the error message gives us:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::fmt::Write;
use std::io::Write as OtherWrite;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut p = String::new();
    (1..6).for_each(|n| {write!(&mut p, "{},", n);} );
    let mut file = File::create("a.csv")?;
    file.write_all(p.as_bytes())?;
    Ok(())
}
```

which compiles OK for me.